# 'Frogs puddle' in Classic Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

[Sewer](https://ak8.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/3897398/thumb/1.jpg?i10c=img.resize(height:160))
I am talking about a puddle area, that, because of that, is grassy, verdant, under this "puddle grass" there is a quiet **sewerish water** (come from a tube),... Name for its puddle frogs

Answer (score 3):

Does **palus, -udis, f.** perhaps fit what you have in mind? Lewis & Short [explain it as](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpalus2) “a swamp, marsh, morass, bog, fen, pool.”

Comment: This pool animals.. Stagni ranas ?